# problems with Blue Pill (stm32f103c8t6) direct register manipulation

Tags: ide, port-mapping, stm32, board

I'm trying to access registers but I keep getting the "was not declared in this scope" error message.
I'm currently using the STM32F1xx boards from http://dan.drown.org/stm32duino/package_STM32duino_index.json

The board package does not seam to recognize any of the registers from the reference manual, mostly trying to access the ADC registers such as 'ADC_CR2'. Does anyone know where I can find the register names which works in the Arduino IDE?

Comment: You probably have to include some special header. No idea what, as it's not anything related to Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko I'm using the "stm32duino" boards, I thought it was connected to Arduino? :S

Comment: stm32duino is a third party package made by Roger Clark. Nothing to do with Ardiuno. Roger's the guy you need to speak to about that core - maybe through github issues if it's hosted there, or find its own forum if there is one.

Comment: https://www.stm32duino.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use something like this:

```
ADC1->CR2 = ... ;
```

note 2 things:

- you need to use `ADC1`, `ADC2` ... to access the registers. not just `ADC`.
- you need to use arrow (->) operator to access the registers

and you may need to include the header file, something like this :

```
#include <stm32f030x6.h>
```

find the proper header file for your MCU. (it's not the same as stm32f1xx, but if proper definitions are made somewhere, it may also work)

Comment: For anyone else having this problem, the registers were called, surprise surprise, ”regs”, so ADC1->regs->CR2.       I still would want to know if theres any easy way to see what a struct contains though, for future problems :)